# What's causing the body tag to widen?

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using [Skeleton CSS Boilerplate](http://getskeleton.com/)

Two different pages of my website, similarly structured, are slightly laterally shifted away from each other. This is causing a jarring effect in the navigation bar when navigating from one page to the other.

Upon investigation, I noticed in the Chrome Dev Tools CSS inspector that the body tag of each page is a different width.

[image: CSS inspector in Chrome Dev Tools shows body tag is 1349px wide]
[image: CSS inspector in Chrome Dev Tools shows body tag is 1366px wide]

The structure of both pages is the same, shown below. The class `.wrap` has a max width of 960px, and all the content is contained within `.container .wrap`.

```
<body>
<?php
    require 'navsub.php';
?>
<div class="container wrap" id="singlepageajax">



</div>
<?php
  include 'footer.php';
?>
</body>
```

*So... what could be causing the body tags to be different widths?*

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: scrollbar could be causing the body tags to be different widths

Comment: @user3896501 I think you're right! That's what seems to be causing this. Is there any way to prevent this? (And to think I literally wasted 3 hours of my time dicking around with the code yesterday --- yeeesh...)

Comment: @user3896501 Where should I put that? In `body` or in `.container.wrap`? (I did try both and neither seemed to have worked, but I'll give it another try after your answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS code

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

then add a `<div id="container-wrapper">` to wrap up the container

place its CSS like

```
#container-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this will enables the scrolling again

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Vertical scroll bar is the cause.

The body element will shrink in horizontal direction to add some free space for the scroll bar, as the browser window has fixed amount of horizontal space.

**UPDATE**

If you want to prevent this behaviour, you may use:

```
body{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

But you may lose the scrolling feature of your browser on the page.

Comment: That indeed seems to be the cause -- is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: That worked, but it got rid of the scroll bar, which I still need.